# How to use GCD to load scene quicker?

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit, xcode8

I'm using spriteKit to develop a game. I'm using scene transition to reload GameScene when player loses. The transition is a laggy. Is it possible to use GCD to fix the problem ? If so please provide code. I'm fairly new to the idea of GCD and there aren't many tutorials for GCD in spriteKit.

Thank you,

Comment: You can load all your assets on background thread and later notify on your main thread, ej: show loading in your main thread, load all your assets on background thread and later remove the loading, if you post some code i can try to help you

Comment: You should really locate the problem rather than guessing. It is likely that you will have to load something on background thread, but it may happen that it is a font issue, or something else. Also, you should show how you make the relevant transition and describe how really "heavy" is the scene that is being loaded.